# cURL and SSL, connect() time out

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm using cURL to connect to a SSL server to recive and send XML-files but I keep getting

> "connect() time out!"

when I try to connect to the server.

I'm kind of new to cURL so I don't know if it's something wrong with the servers configuration, some certificate, or what.

The code i'm trying to run (given to me by the owner of the SSL server):

```
function post($url, $post)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    if($ch)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo '<pre>', curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if(!empty($result))
            return $result;
    }
}
```

cURL version information:

```
[version_number] => 463362
[age] => 3
[features] => 1597
[ssl_version_number] => 0
[version] => 7.18.2
[host] => i486-pc-linux-gnu
[ssl_version] => OpenSSL/0.9.8g
[libz_version] => 1.2.3.3
[protocols] => Array
    (
        [0] => tftp
        [1] => ftp
        [2] => telnet
        [3] => dict
        [4] => ldap
        [5] => ldaps
        [6] => http
        [7] => file
        [8] => https
        [9] => ftps
        [10] => scp
        [11] => sftp
    )
```

Comment: Can you connect through other means? Try using curl from the command line with option `-v` and see how that goes.

Comment: No, that dosnt seem to work either.. I get "Connection timed out".

Comment: Have you tried setting the `CURL_CONNECTTIMEOUT` option?

Comment: Yes I have and I get the same result. If I go to the URL I'm trying to connect to with cURL in a browser it will load in a matter milliseconds.. I thought that might be relevant..

Comment: Probably a networking/firewall problem. Nothing to do with curl or php

Comment: That seems very possible, do you or anyone else know how to check this on a Linux server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message simply means that the TCP connect procedure hasn't completed without the time allowed for the operation.

If you try to connect to a site that should be available over TCP on the given port then you can suspect that there's a firewall, proxy, NAT, router or other equipment in the way that makes it not work for you.

This is not really a curl related problem and you should be able to verify this by for example running telnet to the same host + port: "telnet [host] [port]" as that should also fail.

Comment: Thank you! I added the following rules: `iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` which did the trick.