# Curl "Failed to connect to example.com port 443: Connection timed out" (HTTPS host)

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to send request using CURL but getting a connection timed out error:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'ucn');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

The only problem I have is that it doesn't work for `https://`. What do I need to do to make this work for HTTPS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL and SSL, connect() time out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349350/curl-and-ssl-connect-time-out)